# notify-send with sudo not showing any notifications

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, notifications

**In short:**

I have a scripting finding, fixing and mounting a partition, thus this needs `sudo` / `su` permissions.

**System**: Gnome 16.04 - amd64

`notify-send "a message"` that shows a notification as expected, but

**Problem:**

`sudo notify-send "a message"` does not show anything.

This is since it gets the current user (sudo i.e. root) and attempts to send a notification.

`w` shows my current display as :1, thus

`export DISPLAY=:1; 
sudo notify-send "a message"` also does not show notification

(also tried `DISPLAY=:0`).

I have had a look at a few posts/questions, usually those associated with cron but none of these helped.

In these answers/solutions, they are refering to the `dbus` sessions, etc

links: [link1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron) [link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron) [link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776293/notify-send-not-showing-popup-message)

*I might just be misreading / misunderstanding too :p*

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just do `su <dispay_username> -c 'notify-send "a message"`'

Comment: @林果皞 Hi, thanks for the response. I have discovered how I can get the current active user calling this script :)